# Import python package after installing it with setup.py, without restarting?

Tags: python, package, python-module, setup.py

I have a package that I would like to automatically install and use from within my own Python script.

Right now I have this:

```
>>> # ... code for downloading and un-targzing

>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(['python', 'setup.py', 'install'])
>>> from <package> import <name>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named <package>
```

Then I can continue like this:

```
>>> exit()
$ python
>>> from <package> import <name>
```

And it works just fine. For some reason, Python is able to pick up the package just fine if I restart after running the `setup.py` file, but not if I don't. How can I make it work without having the restart step in the middle?

(Also, is there a superior alternative to using `subprocess.call()` to run `setup.py` within a python script? Seems silly to spawn a whole new Python interpreter from within one, but I don't know how else to pass that install argument.)

Comment: are you using environments at all?

Comment: @riotburn - Not sure what you're talking about, so I'm guessing no? I normally install everything using `pip`, just for some reason one SDK I need isn't available via PyPI - instead the company makes you download a .tar.gz from their website and tells you to run `setup.py` inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your Python version, you want to look into [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) or [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).

e.g. for Python 3, you can do:

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
directory_name = # os.path to module
# where __init__.py is the module entry point
s = SourceFileloader(directory_name, __init__.py).load_module()
```

or, if you're feeling brave that your Python path knows about the directory:

```
map(__import__, 'new_package_name')
```

Comment: +1 on the 'feeling brave' bit - if theres one file wrong in there then the entire import will fall over. I generally go for a loop over the files and import (or import the specific files). I think importlib is only from Python 2.7 and above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275884/import-python-package-after-installing-it-with-setup-py-without-restarting seems to have a lot more details.

Comment: `importlib` works on python3.  I use it [in one of my projects](https://github.com/tristanfisher/yams/blob/master/yams_api/plugins/dev/__init__.py#L20-L26).

Comment: oh yes, i definitely back the use of import lib - its the map bit that I think care is needed around but it all depends how much you trust your imported lib quality. (Sorry- i mispoke, i meant its only from 2.7 upwards... not just only specific 2.7)

Comment: I just noticed one difference thing that changes after I restart python - `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nitro_python-1.0-py2.7.egg` gets added to `sys.path`. Is there some way I can force `sys.path` to reload without restarting Python? Or would manually inserting that path be my best bet (how can I even find that path in a cross-platform way?)

Comment: Oh, Python 2 -- to refresh `sys.path`, you can `import site; reload(site)`

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps,

I downloaded from seaborn from GitHub.

Through command prompt, cd to downloads\seaborn folder

```
python install setup.py
```

Then using spyder from anaconda, checked if it was installed by running the following in a console

```
import pip
sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()])
```

Seeing that it was not there, go to tools and select "Update module names list"

Again trying the previous code in a python console, the lib was still not showing.

Restarting Spyder and trying `import seaborn` worked.

Hope this helps.